# Pass ng-model into a custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I need to make a text box that searches through a javascript array (with objects in it) using angular. It needs to be strict and only return a result once it is exactly matched (So unlike the default filter, if there is no text nothing should be returned). I found a custom filter on here (thanks guys), that did what I wanted with one exception: I cant pass my input ng-model to it. Using the default angular filter I am able to pass ng-model into it like this:

`<input type="text" ng-model="searchID">`

`<div ng-repeat="additive in additives | filter:searchID">`

But when I try do this with my exactMatch filter

```
app.filter('exactMatch', function() {
    return function(additives, pattern) {
        var result = [];
        console.log(pattern);
        additives.forEach(function (additive) {
            if(pattern != "") {
                console.log(pattern);
                if (additive.Number == pattern) {
                    result.push(additive);
                }
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
});
```

It refuses to cooperate, and that `console.log(pattern)` returns undefined.

I also realise that `ng-repeat` might not be the best way to do this since I am only ever returning max 1 object.

Comment: works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/xH7NL/

Comment: I had to remove `.Number` to get Mosho's fiddle to work in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/u2v3d/

Answer (score -1):

You can try removing the filter completely and just showing/hiding elements if they are equal.

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   <input type="text" ng-model="search.searchId">
   <div ng-repeat="additive in data.additives">
       <span ng-show="actions.showIfEqual(additive);">{{additive}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Controller logic:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        additives: ['a','b', 'c', 'd']
    }
    $scope.search = {
        searchId: ''
    };

    $scope.actions = {
        showIfEqual: function (additive) {
            console.log(additive === $scope.search.searchId);
            return additive === $scope.search.searchId;
        }
    };
});
```